# No me muestra el objeto por consola

Tags: javascript, poo

estoy practicando en javascript un poco de POO (clases,constructores y demás). Tengo un formulario(nombre,apellido,telefono) el cual al apretar el botón debería devolverme en consola el objeto que he creado.

Soy nuevo con POO y con todo lo referido al DOM.

```js
   class Person {
    constructor(fname,lname,cphone){
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.cphone = cphone;
     }
    }

    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
      const fname = document.getElementById('name').value;
      const lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
      const cphone = document.getElementById('cphone').value;

      console.log(cphone);

      const personOne = new Person(fname,lname,cphone);
      console.log(personOne.name , personOne.lname , personOne.cphone);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
 <form action="">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="name" 
 placeholder="Nombre...">
            <input type="text" name="apellido" id="lname" 
 placeholder="Apellido...">
            <input type="number" name="cphone" id="cphone" min="0" 
 placeholder="Numero...
            ">
            <button type="submit" id="btn">
                Agregar
            </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y agrega el HTML. De entrada se ve que intentas asignar un listener de tipo `submit`  a un botón, quizá debería ser del tipo `click`, pues un `submit`  aplicaría si el elemento `btn` fuera un formulario.

Comment: como dice el buen @A.Cedano, el boton no tiene el listener de "submit", lo tiene el formulario

Comment: Hola Arturo, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida y conozcas el formato que esperamos al realizar una pregunta, sobre todo qué es un [mcve]. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir lo que consideres que nos puede ayudar a ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Los botones no tienen evento `submit`, por lo tanto, puedes escuchar para este caso el evento `click` del botón.

Por ejemplo:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(fname, lname, cphone) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.cphone = cphone;
  }
}

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const fname = document.getElementById('name').value;
  const lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  const cphone = document.getElementById('cphone').value;

  console.log(cphone);

  const personOne = new Person(fname, lname, cphone);
  console.log(personOne.fname, personOne.lname, personOne.cphone);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="name" placeholder="Nombre...">
  <input type="text" name="apellido" id="lname" placeholder="Apellido...">
  <input type="number" name="cphone" id="cphone" min="0" placeholder="Numero...
            ">
  <button type="submit" id="btn">
                Agregar
            </button>
</form>
```